# How to display a Toast message in the top of the page in my android application

Tags: java, android

I m using the following line to make a Toast message displayed in my android application

```
Toast.makeText(InitActivity.this, InitActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.invalid_pin_code), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But this message is displayed in the bootom of the page.

**And I want to display it below an `EditText` in my page.**

How to make that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need add this as programmatically like this in your code:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

A standard toast notification appears near the bottom of the screen, centered horizontally. You can change this position with the `setGravity(int, int, int)` method. This accepts three parameters: a Gravity constant, an x-position offset, and a y-position offset.

For example, if you decide that the toast should appear in the top-left corner, you can set the gravity like this:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

If you want to nudge the position to the right, increase the value of the second parameter. To nudge it down, increase the value of the last parameter.

Offical Document Source [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#Positioning)

For custom `Toast` check [here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/customiozing-toast-in-android.html)

For making custom position follow [this](https://boltingupandroid.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/repositioning-toast-messages/)

**EDIT : *For making position on particular `View` try this*:**

This code in your `onCreate()` method

```
 editText1 = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 button1 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            makeToast("Hello", editText1);
        }
 });
```

And add this `makeToast(String,View)` method

```
public void makeToast(String text, View v) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int xOffset = 0;
    int yOffset = 0;
    Rect gvr = new Rect();

    View parent = v;// // v is the editText,
    // parent is the rectangle holding it.

    if (parent.getGlobalVisibleRect(gvr)) {

        View root = v.getRootView();

        int halfwayWidth = root.getRight() / 2;
        int halfwayHeight = root.getBottom() / 2;
        // get the horizontal center
        int parentCenterX = ((gvr.right - gvr.left) / 2) + gvr.left;
        // get the vertical center
        int parentCenterY = (gvr.bottom - gvr.top) / 2 + gvr.top;

        if (parentCenterY <= halfwayHeight) {
            yOffset = -(halfwayHeight - parentCenterY);// this image is
                                                        // above the center
                                                        // of gravity, i.e.
                                                        // the halfwayHeight
        } else {
            yOffset = parentCenterY - halfwayHeight;
        }
        if (parentCenterX < halfwayWidth) { // this view is left of center
                                            // xOffset = -(halfwayWidth -
                                            // parentCenterX); } if
                                            // (parentCenterX >=
                                            // halfwayWidth) {
            // this view is right of center
            xOffset = parentCenterX - halfwayWidth;
        }
    }
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, xOffset, yOffset);
    toast.show();

}
```

Comment: How to make it below an EdiText ?

Answer (score 1):

### Displays and centralize your toast at the top

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network issue! Check your internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
View view = toast.getView(); 
view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set gravity of toast. Use this:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(InitActivity.this, 
              InitActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.invalid_pin_code), 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom toast using, like:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);<----- toast location on screen
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Comment: How to make it below an EdiText ?